# Как свернуть многомерный массив в одномерный без потери ключей?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив и выглядит он так:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 884
                    [UF_FIRSTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_MIDDLENAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_LASTNAME] => ТЕСТ                    
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 885
                    [UF_FIRSTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_MIDDLENAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_LASTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                   
                )              

        )

)
```

Нужно привести массив в такой одномерный вид:

```html
Array
(
                    [ID] => 884
                    [UF_FIRSTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_MIDDLENAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_LASTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [ID] => 885
                    [UF_FIRSTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_MIDDLENAME] => ТЕСТ
                    [UF_LASTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                    
)
```

Подскажите как это осуществить? `array_walk_recursive`не подходит мне так как, он расставляет ключи по порядку и исходные ключи теряются.

Comment: То, что Вы хотите не возможно. У Вас получается массив с повторяющимися ключами. Интересно, какое значение Вы ожидаете в ответ на такой вызов: `array["ID"]`

Comment: @Oleg могу ли я сделать тогда хотябы как то индексы одинаковыми у под массивов:
`Array( [0] => (Array[0]=>() Array[0]=>()...)) `

Comment: Одинаковые индексы в рамках одного массива в принципе не возможны. `Array( [0] => (Array[0]=>() Array[1]=>()...))` Вот так можно, да

Comment: Мне нужно как смешать это все в одну кашу, чтобы потом получилась выборка $array[0]["UF_FIRSTNAME"] получил все значения ключей UF_FIRSTNAME...но походу я не в ту степь зашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно как смешать это все в одну кашу, чтобы потом получилась выборка `$array[0]["UF_FIRSTNAME"]` получил все значения ключей `UF_FIRSTNAME`...

с этим вам поможет

```
$result = array_column($array[0], 'UF_FIRSTNAME');
```

Answer (score 1):

Все, что вы можете сделать, это объединить значения подмассивов под одни ключи

```
$array = [
    [
        'ID' => 884,
        'UF_FIRSTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
        'UF_MIDDLENAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
        'UF_LASTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ'
    ],
    [
        'ID' => 885,
        'UF_FIRSTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
        'UF_MIDDLENAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
        'UF_LASTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ'
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        $new[$k][] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: спасибо, код рабочий, но с моим массивом такое почему то не прокатывает((

Comment: @ЕвгенийПивоваров, а вы указывали `$array` (как у меня) или `$array[0]` в цикле?

Comment: И так и так попробовал...

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вам нужно не то, о чём вы спрашиваете. Если вы объясните реальную задачу, то вам смогут помочь.

А пока у меня есть весёлое решение этой проблемы (просто для развлечения):

```
<?php

/**
 * Разворачивает многомерный массив в одномерный, нумеруя ключи
 */
function aflatten(array $arr, string $keyIdSeparator = ''): array {
    $result = [];
    $increments = [];
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item, $key) use($keyIdSeparator, &$result, &$increments) {
        if ( ! isset($increments[$key])) {
            $increments[$key] = 0;
        }
        $newKey = $key . $keyIdSeparator . $increments[$key];
        $result[$newKey] = $item;
        $increments[$key]++;
    });

    return $result;
}

$arr = [
    [
        [
            'ID' => 884,
            'UF_FIRSTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
            'UF_MIDDLENAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
            'UF_LASTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 885,
            'UF_FIRSTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
            'UF_MIDDLENAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
            'UF_LASTNAME' => 'ТЕСТ',
        ],

    ],
];
$keyIdSeparator = '.';
$result = aflatten($arr, $keyIdSeparator);
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $sourceKey = substr($key, 0, strrpos($key, $keyIdSeparator));
    echo $sourceKey, ': ', $value, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял из комментария, то задача при обращении к ключу вывести все его возможные значения из многомерного массива.

Если так то можно замутить вот такое:

```
    $newArray = [];
    $commonArray = Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 884
                            [UF_FIRSTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                            [UF_MIDDLENAME] => ТЕСТ
                            [UF_LASTNAME] => ТЕСТ                    
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 885
                            [UF_FIRSTNAME] => ТЕСТ
                            [UF_MIDDLENAME] => ТЕСТ
                            [UF_LASTNAME] => ТЕСТ

                        )              

                )

        )

foreach ($commonArray as $values) {
    if (!empty($values)) {
       foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
           $newArray[$key][] = $value;
       }
    }
}
```

и далее имеем следующую структуру

```
$newArray = [
   'ID' => [values...],
   'UF_FIRSTNAME' => [values...],
   'UF_MIDDLENAME' => [values...],
   'UF_LASTNAME' => [values...],
]
```

а как вывести это уже следующий вопрос:

[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) - если хотим оставить только уникальные values

[implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) - если хотим вывести в строку с разделителем, например:

```
echo implode(', ', $newArray['UF_FIRSTNAME']); //все значения из ключей UF_FIRSTNAME
```

Если не использовать array_unique, то при переборе по ключам, внутренние указатели значений будут соответствовать, будто они оказались в 1 массиве. Например

```
foreach ($newArray['ID'] as $key => $value) {
    echo 'ID is ' . $value;
    echo 'UF_FIRSTNAME for ID ' . $value . ' is ' . $newArray['UF_FIRSTNAME'][$key];
    // etc
}
```

Надеюсь угадал)